# How to create a new json string by changing one particular field in it?

Tags: java, regex, json, string, gson

I need to blur the user id present in my original json string with another user id. After that I will construct a new json string with everything same but the only difference will be the user id is different.

As an example, if my original json string is like this -

```
{
 "user_id":{"long":1234},
 "client_id":{"int":0},
 "affinity":[
              {
               "try":{"long":55793},
               "scoring":{"float":0.19}
               },
               {
                "try":{"long":1763},
                "scoring":{"float":0.0114}
               }
            ]
}
```

Then my new json string will be - The only difference is I have a new user id in it and apart from that everything is same.

```
{
 "user_id":{"long":98765},
 "client_id":{"int":0},
 "affinity": [ 
               {
                 "try":{"long":55793},
                 "scoring":{"float":0.19}
               },
               {
                 "try":{"long":1763},
                 "scoring":{"float":0.0114}
               }
             ]
}
```

The only problem I have is, I won't have json string in the above format only so I cannot use POJO to serialize my json string since my json string will have different formats but `user_id` field will always be like that in all my json string and it will be `long` as well. The other fields might be different depending on the json string I have.

I am using `Gson` to do this. I have got the below method but not sure how can I construct a new json with `newUserId` in it and everything should be same?

```
private static String creatNewJson(String originalJsonResponse, long newUserId) {
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(originalJsonResponse);
    JsonObject jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
    jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("user_id");

    // not sure what I should do here to construct a new json with newUserId

}
```

Or `Gson` is not the right way to do this? Should I be usingg regular expressions for this?

Comment: you can try this
`jsobject.remove("long");
jsobject.addProperty("long",newValue)`

Comment: Then how would I construct the full json string with this jObject?

Comment: its easy you can do that using `GSON.toJson(jsonObject);`
http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(com.google.gson.JsonElement)

Comment: @viditbhatia aahh. Slightly confuse, how do I make sure `jsonObject` has everything in it all the fields including newUserId field in it.

Comment: So because we have not made any change to any other field it will be exactly same as the original one.  but if you still want to check you can do it by using the `has(memberName)` function on `jsonobject`. and check its value. using the `getproperty(membername)` function on jsonObject.  http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `input.replaceAll("(\"user_id\":\\{\"long\":)\\d+", "$1" + newID)`?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. If possible, can you add little bit explanation for my understanding purpose? What does $1 mean here?

Comment: `$1` means "the string that matched the part of regex in the first pair of parenthesis", which in this case is everything preceding the digits (actual id). In this case (because we know the exact string we are looking for), we could just use `"user_id:{\"long\":"` instead, but `$1` is shorter.
You can read more about `replaceAll` in regex in general in jdk documentation: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: @Dima, you can edit your answer to update it so you'd have better formatting options to make it easier to read